# Ingress hacking streak back to '0' despite definite hacking within 24 hrs

Tags: ingress

I had a hacking streak (sojourner) of 71 days and did my first hack of the day on day 72 (31 August), only to discover it had gone back to '0'. Why has this happened. I definitely did not miss the 24hr reset time as I was actually out and about 4 hours earlier than I would normally have been. To say I was really annoyed about this is an understatement!

Comment: Has it by now started counting again?

Comment: Also I frequently find myself looking at the stat below in _Mentoring_. It's the _Agents Successfully Recruited_ which says 1 for me and only started showing up when I got that first one. I freak out every time I see that 1. :P